# reset binding in popup

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to programmatically select items in the popup of a custom editable multiselect combobox.
I've restyled the comboboxes popup to deal with selected items:

```
<Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Right">
            <themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}">
                <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                        <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                            <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="opaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dropDownBorder}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <ListBox x:Name="ListBox" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}" 
                                     KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Focusable="False"
                                     SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            </ListBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
        </Popup>
```

I can do the following succesfully:

```
    if (_temporarySelectedItem != null)
        {
            var item = _model.OptionItems.Single(x => x.Name.Equals(_temporarySelectedItem.Name));
            item.IsSelected = true;
            ItemsSource = _model.OptionItems;
        }
```

The correct item gets selected however after the first time no changes can be made. In other words. If I have items a,b, and c in the pop up and I set a to be selected, the popup shows it as selected, but if I then set b to be selected no change is observed (inspecting the ItemsSource at this point shows that the item does in fact have its IsSelected set to true).

Any ideas on how to get the listbox to redraw?

Comment: You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your data item class and raise `PropertyChanged` events accordingly.